# Multiple dropdowns remember their last state- jquery, cookies or localStorage?

Tags: jquery, cookies, drop-down-menu, navigation, local-storage

I'm trying to use dropdowns for some site navigation and would like them to remember their last selected state either with jQuery cookies or localStorage. However, some dropdowns have a secondary dropdown that appears with more options.

The basic setup is:

```
form
    fieldset
        select.select_class#select-writing
            option(value='') Select
            option(value='books') Books
            option(value='articles') Articles
            option(value='quotes') Quotes
            option(value='suggested-readings') Suggested Readings

    fieldset.hide#select-writing-books
        select.select_class
            option(value='') Choose a book...
            option(value='thoughts') Thoughts on Design
            option(value='trademark') Trademark Design
            option(value='iKnow') I Know a Lot of Things
            option(value='sparkle') Sparkle and Spin
            option(value='trademarkSelection') The Trademarks of Paul Rand — A Selection
            option(value='little1') Little 1
            option(value='listen') Listen! Listen!

            button.hide#select-writing-books-button(href="#") Go
```

And my JS is:

```
$('#select-writing').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "books") {
        $("#select-writing-books").show();
    } else {
        $("#select-writing-books").hide();
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "articles") {
        $("#select-writing-articles").show();
    } else {
        $("#select-writing-articles").hide();
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "quotes") {
        $("#select-writing-quotes").show();
    } else {
        $("#select-writing-quotes").hide();
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "suggested-readings") {
        $("#select-writing-suggested-readings").show();
    } else {
        $("#select-writing-suggested-readings").hide();
    }
});
```

If someone selects a dropdown that has a 2nd dropdown, they would both still show on refresh/revisit, etc.

I have tried using the jquery-cookie plugin with this code, but the 2nd dropdown does not appear:

```
if($.cookie('remember_select') != null) {
    // set the option to selected that corresponds to what the cookie is set to
    $('.select_class option[value="' + $.cookie('remember_select') + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
}

// when a new option is selected this is triggered
$('.select_class').change(function() {
    // new cookie is set when the option is changed
    $.cookie('remember_select', $('.select_class option:selected').val());
});
```

The code works, but is there a cleaner, more concise way to write it for several other dropdown instances?

A working demo can be seen here: http://paulrand.design/_r@nd20i5/_template-article.html

I'd also like to use the plug SelectOrDie for styling the dropdown itself, but there seems to be some conflicts (http://vst.mn/selectordie/). An example with that working is here: http://paulrand.design/_r@nd20i5/_template-list-with-thumbnails.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to store across different visits/reloads, you need a storage system that isn't in the client, because when you reload the page, the javascript will basically start from scratch all over again.

Cookies would seem to be the obvious choice, although local storage would also work. Basically, you're on the right track. There's no fancy function inside Javascript that will remember a variable's value between page reloads. You have to store it outside the page, somewhere.

Also, if your site has a login, and you want to make it client independent, you could use AJAX to store the values in a database, writing them each time the select fires an onChange.

Either way, you have to write them somewhere else whenever the user makes a change, then read them all back in either when you need them or on pageload.